# How to get index of yield?

Tags: python, yield

I have such code:

```
def iter_commit(LogFileName):
    with open(path.join(__folder__, LogFileName)) as LogFileName_file:
        for index, schema in enumerate(LogFileName_file):
            if len(schema) > 10:
                yield index, schema.rstrip('\n')

def makePool(cP, func, iters):
    try:
        pool = ThreadPool(cP)

        pool.map_async(func,iters).get(99999)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    except:
        print('Pool Error')
        raise
    finally:
        pool.terminate()

def Parse(RoWnum, Link):
    print(RoWnum, Link)


makePool(50, partial(Parse, iter_commit(strSiteMap)[0]),
                            iter_commit(strSiteMap)[1])
```

But I'm geting error `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

So how to get index of `yield`?

Comment: You need to call `next()` or use `itertools.islice()`

Comment: save value from generator and after that `item[]`

Comment: e.g. `gen = iter_commit(strSiteMap); first = next(gen); second = next(gen)`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something like `map(Parse, iter_commit(strSiteMap))`?

Comment: Why i need to? only map_async can be interupted by ctrl+c ?

Comment: when you first access the iterator it constructs it, so you need to use `next()` as the first comment mentions. In your case it would be `next(iter_commit(strSiteMap))[0]`

Comment: If you want `index`, you need to subscript a value yielded by the generator, not the generator itself. It's unlikely you want to call the iterator twice with the same argument.

Comment: Please show un example within my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not fully understand what you're trying to do, but perhaps the following, which doesn't use `functools.partial()`, might help because it works without needing the index value. What it does is pass your `makePool()` function an iterator which will produce the paired values the `Parse()` function expects and passes them as a tuple.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

strSiteMap = ['site0', 13, 'site1', 42]

def makePool(cP, func, iters):
    try:
        pool = ThreadPool(cP)

        pool.map_async(func, iters).get(99999)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    except Exception:
        print('Pool Error')
        raise
    finally:
        pool.terminate()

def Parse(args):
    RowNum, Link = args
    print('Parse({!r}, {!r}) called'.format(RowNum, Link))

makePool(50, Parse, pairwise(strSiteMap))
```